# Django-registration form without email field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-registration

I've read through several similar questions here, but I still can't seem to find a solution:

I am using the [django-registration](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration) package and I want to make a registration form that does not have an email field, or at least not required.  I have tried many different ways, but here is one:

```
# in forms.py
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class ExpRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    # email = forms.EmailField(label="E-mail",required=False)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].required = False
```

Then I link this to a custom view:

```
# in views.py
from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView as BaseRegistrationView

class ExpRegistrationView(BaseRegistrationView):
    form_class = ExpRegistrationForm
```

Then in urls, after importing views, I add to urlpatterns:

```
url(r'^../accounts/register/$',views.ExpRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register')
```

I've shown two attempts above, but I also tried using del or pop to try to get rid of email from my form...  And I always get a field error, saying that email is required...

Any suggestions?  Or more information needed?

Comment: I assume you already have a custom Django user class set up as shown here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Did you try to exclude the email field like here under 2): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use

Comment: Here, excluding email field is not an option, as I can see, it sends email after a registration is successful hence an email field is required for where the mail should be sent.